# Isolated scope with reload event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m actually creating a directive that permit me to generate some graphs, with some parameters at this format :

```
<div anomalie-graph idsite="{{site._id}}" sector="true" controlleur="" anomalie=""
                     datedebut="dateDebutStats"
                     datefin="dateFinStats">
```

or

```
<div anomalie-graph idsite="{{site._id}}" sector="" controlleur="" anomalie="true"
                     datedebut="dateDebutStats"
                     datefin="dateFinStats">
```

This directive display correctly what I need.
The problem is that I want to reload the data inside this directive.

In fact, I use something like :

```
  $scope.$on('reload', function () {
                reload();
            });
```

Inside of the directive controller.

Now that I have isolated my scope with

```
return {
            restrict: 'EAC',
            templateUrl: 'tpl/directive/TraitementAnomalieGraphDirective.html',
            controller: controller,
            scope: {
                idsite: '@',
                sector: '@',
                controlleur: '@',
                anomalie: '@',
                datedebut: '@',
                datefin: '@'

            }
        };
```

I cant listen to the scope event (because it's isolated), and I dont want to use $scope.$broadcast.

Before scope isolation, it worked great with the listener events. The problem was that I couldn't use this library multiple time in a view...

Can you help me ?

EDIT:

Here's my code :

Template:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div anomalie-graph idsite="{{site._id}}" sector="true" controlleur="" anomalie=""
                     datedebut="dateDebutStats"
                     datefin="dateFinStats">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div anomalie-graph idsite="{{site._id}}" sector="" controlleur="true" anomalie=""
                     datedebut="dateDebutStats"
                     datefin="dateFinStats">
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
```

Here's the directive :

angular.module('app')
    .directive('anomalieGraph', function () {

```
    var controller = ['$scope', '$attrs', 'srv_traitementsVoirie', function ($scope, $attrs, srv_traitementsVoirie) {


        var load = function () {
            // code of reload
        };

        load();

        $scope.$on('reload', function () {
            load();
        });

    }];

    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        templateUrl: 'tpl/directive/TraitementAnomalieGraphDirective.html',
        controller: controller,
        scope: {
            idsite: '@',
            sector: '@',
            controlleur: '@',
            anomalie: '@',
            datedebut: '=',
            datefin: '='

        }
    };
});
```

Comment: From where are you broadcasting/emitting event "reload" which you are trying to listen in your directive's controller.

Comment: In the parent controller (the parent view loads the directive)

Comment: Using $scope.$broadcast or $scope.$emit?

Comment: $scope.$emit('reload')

Comment: I will suggest you to use "$rootScope.$emit" instead of $scope.$emit or $scope.$broadcast because $rootScope.$emit travel form root towards down for tracing listeners, and it will cover your situation.

Comment: Like explained, I dont want to use $broadcast neither $rootScope to avoid other problems bound to those

Comment: Can you pls share a plunkr of the code?